# The data in my Google Sheet is not appearing in the correct cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet to simplify our account returns. I am using a variety of named ranges to make life easier. I have created a test sheet which automatically copies the inputted cost to its appropriate category.

I am having a strange issue where the cell I am expecting to see the data in is incorrect. I am wondering if the 2 data validation lists I have created could be causing the issue. I had originally copy / pasted from an old sheet but as I wondered if some strange formatting may have been carried over which is causing the issue I have since manually entered all data to remove this as a potential cause.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KC8FsVNQZfWtey5TvPDxCxvDhRrFVHdsbDJWmZu73wg/edit#gid=0

This is the test sheet in question. The cost for entries Test 9 & Test 10 should be in the Info Books and Stationary sections retrospectively but they are ending up in the wrong places.

I am not a spreadsheet expert so I apologise if I am missing something blatently obvious. A friend advised me to ask on Stackoverflow after many hours lost to this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the third parameter in vlookup set to false (or zero)

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(companyOfPurchase,suppliersAndCategories,2, 0) = typeOfPurchase,totalOfReceipt,"")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Comment: Hi @WayneMcNamara, if this answer was helpful or solved your issue please upvote or accept the answer. Thanks.